# Where date is later than

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, expressionengine

I am storing a date as 'd-m-Y H:i:s'.

I need to check if this stored date is later than the `$limit_date` variable. The `$limit_date` variable is -30 days of the current date, stored in 'd-m-Y'.

I had thought the following would work, but no results are returned.

```
$limit_date = strtotime('-30 day');
$limit_date = date("d-m-Y", $limit_date);

$this->db->where('date_submitted >', $limit_date);
```

My test `date_submitted` is '`25-04-2017 09:13:13`' with `$limit_date` returning '26-03-2017'.

Comment: Have you tried adding using `d-m-Y H:i:s` when formatting `$limit_date`? You would be better using the date formatted in the UNIX time format and then working out whether the dates are later than what is stored.

Comment: _“My test date_submitted is '25-04-2017 09:13:13' with $limit_date returning '26-03-2017'”_ – you are comparing _strings_ here, and that happens character-by-character. The first character is `2` in both values, so we have to look at the next one - `5` and `6`, `6` is a “greater” character than `5`, so not match. // Use a proper date column type in your table, and then use MySQL date/time functions to create the interval for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code we are using `DateTime` and `DateInterval`. `DateInterval` for subtracting an exact amount of days you want to.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782307)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$days=30;
$object = new DateTime("25-04-2017 09:13:13");//giving the date from which we want to subtract.
$object->sub(new DateInterval("P".$days."D"));//passing the interval which we want to subtract
echo $object->format("d-m-Y H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$limit_date = strtotime('-30 day');
$limit_date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $limit_date);

$this->db->where('date_submitted >', $limit_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to change date field string to date

STR_TO_DATE(date_submitted, '%Y-%m-%d')

```
$limit_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));

$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(date_submitted, '%Y-%m-%d') >', $limit_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you converted for the query the date_submitted in your DB to DATE if you don't want to mess with hours:minutes:seconds

Example:

```
$limit_date = strtotime('-30 day');
$limit_date = date("d-m-Y", $limit_date);
$this->db->where('DATE(date_submitted) >', $limit_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
WHERE date_submitted > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY) // for 30days
```

or

```
WHERE date_submitted > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY) // for 30*24hours
```